# Pandas new col with indexes of rows sharing a code in another col

Tags: python, pandas

Let say I've a DataFrame indexed on unique Code. Each entry may herit from another (unique) entry: the parent's Code is given in col Herit.

I need a new column giving the list of children for every entries. I can obtain it providing the Code, but I don't succeed in setting up the whole column.

Here is my M(non)WE:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Code": ["a", "aa", "ab", "b", "ba", "c"],
    "Herit":  ["", "a", "a", "", "b", ""],
    "C": [12, 15, 13, 12, 14, 10]
    }
)
data.set_index("Code", inplace=True)
print(data)

child_a = data[data.Herit == "a"].index.values
print(child_a)

data["child"] = data.apply(lambda x: data[data.Herit == x.index].index.values, axis=1)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the `Herit` column and then reduce the corresponding `Code`s into lists:

```
>>> herits = df.groupby("Herit").Code.agg(list)
>>> herits

Herit
     [a, b, c]
a     [aa, ab]
b         [ba]
```

Then you can `map` the `Code` column of your frame with this and assign to a new column and fill the slots who don't have any children with `""`:

```
>>> df["Children"] = df.Code.map(herits).fillna("")
>>> df

  Code Herit   C  Children
0    a        12  [aa, ab]
1   aa     a  15
2   ab     a  13
3    b        12      [ba]
4   ba     b  14
5    c        10
```

Comment: Works well, unless I use `df.set_index("Code", inplace=True)`. Thus I've got `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Code'`

Comment: @NBur I think you already set `Code` as the index. Can you please say what `print(df.index.name)` gives?

Comment: I use something similar to the MWE. My df comes from a csv… `df.index.name` gives `Code`

Comment: @NBur I see, then please do `df = df.reset_index()` before running the above code. Then you can go for `df = df.set_index("Code")` at the end. Reason is to make use of `Code` as a *column* not an *index* during the computations. But after the computations we can of course set it back as the index.